# Multi Search in Table

Tags: php, search

How can I perform a multi-search in a table in PHP?

Here's my code:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Cari Nama" name="carinama" style="margin-top:10px;" />
    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Cari DOB" name="caridob" id="datepicker" autocomplete="off"style="margin-top:10px;" />
    <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Cari Role" name="carirole" style="margin-top:10px;" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i> Cari</button>
</form>
```

Here, this is the `querynumber`:

```
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid row-merge">
<?php
    $querymember = "SELECT u.*, r.* FROM m_user u LEFT JOIN m_role r ON u.user_role = r.role_id ";
    if(isset($_GET['carinama']))
    {
        $carinama = $_GET['carinama'];
        $querymember .= " WHERE u.user_email LIKE '%$carinama%' OR u.user_fname LIKE '%$carinama%' OR u.user_mname LIKE '%$carinama%' OR u.user_lname LIKE '%$carinama%' OR u.user_uname LIKE '%$carinama%' OR u.user_fname LIKE '%$carinama%'";
        echo "Filter : $carinama";
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['caridob']))
    {
        $caridob = $_GET['caridob'];
        $querymember .= " WHERE u.user_dob LIKE '%$caridob%'";
        echo "Filter : $caridob";
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['carirole']))
    {
        $carirole = $_GET['carirole'];
        $querymember .= " WHERE r.role_name LIKE '%$carirole%'";
        echo "Filter : $carirole";
    }

    $querymember .= " ORDER BY u.user_fname";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$querymember);
    $rpp = 10; // results per page
    $_SESSION['filter']=$querymember;
    $adjacents = 4;
```

I am still a newbie, so I need your help. I would be grateful for this. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (lower(CONCAT(u.user_email,u.user_fname,u.user_mname,u.user_lname,u.user_uname,u.user_fname)) LIKE '%LOWER('.$carinama.')%')
```

Comment: sorry. i'm using value in the input type.

Comment: value="<?php if(isset($_GET['carinama'])) {echo $_GET['carinama'];} else {echo"";} ?>"